# How to make TODAY function static with a script

Tags: google-sheets

I have a cell that needs to lock the day when something is approved. I have tried many formulas, but this might need a script.

This is the formula:

```
=IF(R17=0, TODAY())
```

[Link to file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N-7SCqbKAnhv-6AqKut0XeegV_b6m-8ZKnGqlcVdDqE/edit#gid=1467247699)

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It does require script. This will freeze the date when approved.

```
function onEdit(e){
   var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName()
   var editRow=e.range.getSheet().getActiveCell().getRow()
   var editColumn=e.range.getSheet().getActiveCell().getColumn()
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() 
   var s=ss.getSheetByName("Show Management")//get sheet by name
   var Ap=s.getRange(editRow,11,1,1).getValue() 
   if(sheet!="Show Management"){return}
   if(editColumn==11 && editRow>=12 && Ap=="Approved"){
     var d=s.getRange(editRow,27.1,1).getValue().toString()
       if(d="[object Date]"){
         var cpy=s.getRange(editRow,27 ,1, 1).getDisplayValue()
         var cpyVal=s.getRange(editRow,27 ,1, 1).setValue(cpy)
  }
  }}
```

Here is my shared test spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qIfVfLTOpjOHaOP8_1_I3B8uteBCX-yj-TjxkGkTv1c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: How do I insert this into the specific cells needed?

Comment: See revised script and shared spreadsheet. I think this is what you are asking. It handles all rows in column 11 the same.

Comment: Hello Ed - the date still changed. Can I email you the live document....https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N-7SCqbKAnhv-6AqKut0XeegV_b6m-8ZKnGqlcVdDqE/edit#gid=1467247699

Comment: I made a copy of your spreadsheet, changed 'Approved' in K to something else then changed it to approved. The date in AA no longer has a formula (which is why it won't change). What exactly are you doing to cause a problem?

Comment: Hi - So i need to capture a static date in AA, only when R is "0"....which is triggered by column K - So when an item is waiting on approval the R shows the total sqft.....once approved, printed, ect...R defaults to "0" and triggers AA to use the TODAY function to capture the date it left the waiting on approval stage....but it wont stay static....hope this make sense...and thank you

Comment: This conversation is getting rather long, which SO doesn't like. You can reach me at ednelson@sbcglobal.net. Right now when K goes to 'Approved' onEdit gets the today() date in AA and then overwrtes the formula in AA with just the date. What else should it check for?